# Angularjs и jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Здравствуйте. Я ни разу не работал с ангуляром, работал только с jQuery. Сейчас хочу начать учить ангуляр, и возник такой вопрос.

- Можно ли использовать ангуляр и jquery вместе? Просто, если использовать 1 ангуляр, тогда же не будит работать ui.  Всякие выпадающие меню при наведении, модальные окна и тд. Или ангуляр тоже можно как ui использовать?
- Второй вопрос: Если отказаться от jquery и использовать только angular, то такие плагины как select2 или datetimepicker не будут работать. Как с этим быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не стесняйтесь подключать jquery.
еще [lodash](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) подключите и возможно сразу [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Это сарказм?) или вы серьезно?

Comment: вполне серьезно, причин подключить `jquery` много, а вод причин не подключать ну не знаю...

Comment: Это и хотел узнать. Спасибо)

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, возможно вам и не нужно подключать jquery так как она есть внутри angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element